# Xampp Mysql wont start

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have read all the posts about this none fix it? please help ive even tryed re-installing my computer and reinstalling xampp

Errors:

```
00:33:43  [mysql]   Problem detected!
00:33:43  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
00:33:43  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
00:33:43  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
00:33:43  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
00:33:43  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Then i get a user account control to allow changes when i try to start mysql? something to do with net.exe? in C:\Windows, im not sure of the rest of the directory

If i say no to the user account cocntrol then it says this
00:33:49  [mysql]   There may be an error, return code: 1223 - The operation was cancelled by the user.

If i say yes nothing happens? Apparently its windows 5.1 erroring? but the directory doesnt even exist? i deleted it all from Program Files and Program Files (x86), Also uninstalled all mysql components? Any thoughts

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed already?  Seems like it.

Comment: What do you mean?, Only thing to do with mysql i have is xampps mysql, like i said ive removed all components of mysql server 5.1 and 5.5

Comment: It says in the error message that MySQL is already running on port 3306 - have you tried typing in `mysql` at the command prompt?

Comment: Thats what im asking, its really weird because i have no mysql? ive tryed adding a new 3306 port and tryed changing it to 3307 in my.ini in C:\Xampp\MySql\Bin

Comment: Have you gone to `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini`?

Comment: That doesn't exist, i deleted the folder of MySQL Server 5.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [xampp MySQL does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was using standalone `MySQl` for Java, and then I install `XAMPP` even after uninstalling stand-alone `MySQL`, `XAMPP MySQL` wouldn't start. 
The problem is even after uninstalling MySQL `MySQL service` is normally still in the registry. The solution is to remove `MySQL service` from `registry`. The easiest way to do this, run `XAMP-control` in `Administrator` mode, and remove `MySQL` from `service` list and start `MySQL` again. That's it

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to know the program, use `netstat -ao`

You have the port and the associated pid.

Get the pid for 3306.

Then launch `taskmgr`

Show column `pid` (Menu > Select > Column selection > check PID)

- You know the program which uses this 3306 port.
- Kill it
- Restart your XAMP

Then for not starting this "3306 port" program, launch `services.msc`.

It is certainly a MySQL, search for it and desactivate it at startup.

Comment: Ive tryed this, no port is showing on cmd with netstat -ao , for 3306 , and when i start mysql now it just says 15:46:48  [mysql]  Attempting to start MySQL service... ,and doesnt show a error

Answer (score 0):

yes i already get this, the problem is that you already install MySQL as standalone version OR with VM i guess , and then you install xampp, the solution for that, is open process monitor, and close MySQL, MySQL Server 5.1 then you can start xampp and will work fine ^^

Answer (score 0):

In my case I checked the:

> mysql_error.log

And found the problem with:

```
[ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files

[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.

[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
```

Then, I run the command:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin>aria_chk -r ..\data\mysql\*.MAI
```

After that mysql runs without any issues

Answer (score -1):

I just uninstall the register service using

```
 sc delete MySQL
```

and restart my xmapp service; then it works OK.

Answer (score -2):

close Xampp server
go to C:\xampp\mysql\data
delete the ibdata1 file
restart xampp server