# Xampp Mysql Port Issue

Tags: mysql, service, xampp, port, ports

Im having problems starting my MYSQL server on my Xampp. This is the error I get:

```
13:03:54  [mysql]   Problem detected!
13:03:54  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt.exe"     "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\bin\my.cnf" mysql"!
13:03:54  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:03:54  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:03:54  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:03:54  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

I have changed the ports in the **my.ini** file to 3307 and other and I still receive this error. I also tried changing the port from the **Config** button in the Xampp console and changing the MYSQL port to 3307 but this only removes the error and Attempts to start the service without success.

I have also reinstalled the program but this also didnt fix the issue.

Im using a Windows Vista 32 bit

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An instance of mysql is already up and running.

Comment: @VMai How is that possible??

Comment: Maybe it's installed as a service. You should check the services applet.

Comment: @VMai I do see a mysql.exe service but when I disable it my Xampp mysql service still doesnt work

Comment: Please have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/452262/how-to-remove-mysql-service-from-windows

Comment: possible duplicate of [xampp MySQL does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)