# How can I get mysql server to work in xampp?

Tags: php, xampp

I have recently installed xampp in windows 7. When I try to run Mysql I get the following error:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:27:51 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:27:51 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:27:51 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:27:51 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:27:51 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
12:27:51 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

Within my.ini I have changed the port from 3306 to 3307 because I have a different mysql server 5.6.19 running in my computer as well. But still i get the same error. Please can anyone help me???? I also uninstalled Xampp and installed it again :(.

Comment: Use openfire for all in one solution

Comment: Have you pressed the logs button? What are the last few lines?

Comment: @Mark: openfire is a jabber server. what does it have to do with getting mysql running?

Comment: yes I have checked that.

Comment: 2014-06-09 12:44:04 8696 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-06-09 12:44:04 8696 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-06-09 12:44:04 8696 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-06-09 12:44:04 8696 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-06-09 12:44:04 8696 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-06-09 12:44:04 8696 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-06-09 12:44:04 8696 [Note] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete @Lee

Comment: Try again press the log button immediately after the error. Ignore all [Note]s search for [Warning] or better [Error]

Comment: Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory
 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
 [ERROR] Aborting @Lee

Comment: Seems that changing the port has not worked correctly.
The solution can be found here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start

Comment: @Lee I tried that already. went to my.ini, but didn't work. Thank you though

Comment: @Lee You were right. the way I changed the port was not right

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this same issue not 10 minutes ago.

1. Open XAMPP
2. Click on Config
3. Click on Service and Port Settings
4. Click MySQL tab
5. Change Main Port
6. Click Save
7. Then restart the MySQL service

Comment: I have tried that before, but still get the same error. I also changed my.ini.

Comment: There are a couple of place to change. In my.ini: port, master-port
In php.ini: mysql.default_port, mysqli.default_port.  Did you update all four by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Experienced this before try to close all your chatting program like skype and etc. cause it uses the same port as xampp port 80, after closing now you can re-open it after running xamp

Comment: The problem is not apache. My problem is with Mysql and the port 3306

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before and the only solution I found was to use an older version of XAMPP. I'm not at my home PC at the moment and can't give you the exact version that worked for me at this moment, but I will post it in the comments later if it helps (my best guess is 1.7.5).

In the meantime, if you are using the newest version of XAMPP you might try an older version.