# xampp MySQL is not running

Tags: mysql, xampp

Problem detected!

```
10:30:09 PM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
10:30:09 PM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
10:30:09 PM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
10:30:09 PM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I have tried these links but nothing happened.

- http://chanakaudaya.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/solution-for-xampp-server-mysql-service-not-starting-on-port-3306-error/
- [xampp MySQL does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)

Comment: possible duplicate of [xampp MySQL does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is not starting because it cannot bind to the default port: 3306 -you have an old instance still running. You should stop it first. If the GUI you are using does not identify it or cannot connect to the running instance, try opening a console and running `mysqladmin -u root shutdown`.

Worst case scenario (your mysql server is not responding), kill the mysqld process using the GUI or `taskkill`.