# XAMPP not starting SQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP to use mysql and php. When I go to start MySQL I get this error

```
Problem detected!
Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" MySQL"!
MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I have seen others ask this question, but no solutions are working for me.

Some just say " Stop the sevice" I have, then when I go to start it using XAMPP, the same service runs and I get the same error.

I seen one solution as "go to my.ini and change all instances of port 3306 to 3307". I did that, and I still get this error.

Comment: You running any antivirus?

Comment: I have Avast running.

Comment: Have you tried adding xampp to the allowed list in your firewall? (on those ports essentially?)

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I had similar issue.

It occured that the cause of such error in my case was that before I've installed xampp, I installed standalone version of MySQL downloaded from Oracle site.

I think that in your case the situation might be the same.

The message Port 3306 in use by `""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld" MySQL"!` most probably says that in your system, there is already mysql service running.

Comment: I would rather not, uninstall where I use this in my Java but . If I have to , for now I will. Or try and set something else up. What do i need to uninstall exactly, so that I am not removing the wrong thing.

Comment: Please look at @Sumisuy answer - I think he is right about setting another port for xampp  mysql, so it would allow you to have 2 instances running at the same time. I think that Sumisuy answer should help you solve your problem.

Comment: Ok but for that, am I changing the port in the origional mysql or the mysql in xampp? Because when I did it in xampp it did nothing( as in it still didn't work and I got the same error)

Comment: I think here you can find some help: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start**

Comment: xampp/mysql/bin/my-ini

Comment: Thanks. As for the link, please look especially at @JohnHogan answer, he writes about it in details. Hope that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68846/discussion-between-t-g-and-kalkrin).

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.. I went into localhost on my browser. the xampp page came up. I went to security and changed the password. It then let me access phpmyadmin(it wasn't before). Then my php kept saying that it wasn't connecting accessing still. I actually ran the php file in localhost under a folder I made in "C://Xampp/htdocs/filename" so localhost/filename. it showed the directory for that file and it said connected. It must have had everything to do wit the fact I was running it on my school's public space. for what ever reason ( it was running apache ) 
I never even had to change anything in my sql files and I still don't have sql running in xampp. Just apache.

Thank you to everyone who tried to assist me.