# My SQL cant run on Xampp

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I have xampp installed on my computer. I recently installed Mysql server 5.1 and ISS on my computer. I noticed after that that Apache and MySql server dont run anymore n xampp. I tried changinf ports for both of them but only Apache works and when I go to the Apache admin page the following IIS7 screen comes up:
[image]

The other problem is even that mySql is still showing me the same problem. Changing ports didn't work. Here is what I see on apache

[image]

I tired the following solution: [solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)and [solution2](http://www.lukebrowning.com/blog/nt-kernel-system-using-port-80/) but nothing of these works unfortunately. 
How can I run my ex mySql configration again on xampp? And how can retun back to my apache local host page ?

Answer (score 0):

please follow the steps mentioned in the post http://careerstage.blogspot.in/2013/08/port-3306-in-use-by-mysqldexe-mysql.html to resolve this issue

Comment: This doesent work. It is smilar to solution that I already said that I tried.

Comment: I am not seeking to delete the newly installed SQL server. I need to run both of them.

Comment: I tried it. I changed the port but it insists on running on the port 3306

Comment: Insist .. how did you changed the port . Change in the configuration my.cnf with new port. Make sure to restart the mysqld service from command prompt .. In case of error while restarting please port it here ..

Comment: Yes I made that. It still has the following output                                                      08:56:37  [mysql]  Problem detected!
08:56:37  [mysql]  Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
08:56:37  [mysql]  MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
08:56:37  [mysql]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
08:56:37  [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: I dont know why this happens even I changed the port

Comment: Ok .. it seems you may be changing the wrong configuration file. The configuration file is in the data folder instead of whether mysql is installed . It should be in C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Program...\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 and there you need to change it ..

Comment: The file Ihave changed is called my.ini

Comment: Yes but its in the wrong path .... Locate the data folder ..... or run the command mysql --verbose --help and search for my.ini file .. and there you need to make the changes in the ini file                                                                                                    ...                                                 Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf 
The following groups are read: mysql client