# XAMPP - MySQL shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, windows-8.1

I installed XAMPP on Windows 8 (64bit). In XAMPP Control Panel i can't start mySQL. I changed the port of mySQl in "C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini" from 3306 to 3307 according to that link:

[xampp MySQL does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start/23864436#23864436?newreg=6b2cce5dedf544dcbcf20f65356f97e5)

now the code in "my.ini" changed to:

```
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3307
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
port= 3307
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
```

Now it still gives that error:

```
11:31:48 AM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL service...
11:31:56 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: running
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    Status change detected: stopped
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
11:32:01 AM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums
```

I deleted "ibdata1" file in "C:\xampp\mysql\data".

also stopped mysql56 service.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: "Press the Logs button to view error logs and check"

Comment: try using netstat to cek blocked port and the available port.
if the 3306 port is in used.try to close that process.so you don't need to change the port.

Answer (score 1):

Check the error logs to view more details on the subject. Check that `mysql` and `mysqli` port options in `my.ini` and `php.ini` and in `config.inc.php` match and are `3307`.

In case `MySQL` Server has crashed you might want to take a look at [Forcing InnoDB Recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

In addition take also a look at this [solution](https://www.quora.com/MySQL-shutdown-unexpectedly-in-XAMPP-How-can-I-fix-it) in case it is a 3rd party software issue.

Comment: How is php.ini related to mysql shutdown unexpectedly?

Comment: @Jigar this is a more detailed solution. To be more accurate one needs to see error log. Thanks for the comment, previous answer was not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Peter said, you need to change that file configuration.

Try to change this in your xampp folder ex: `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`:

```
mysql.default_port=3307
mysqli.default_port=3307
```

And change this parameter in your xampp folder ex: `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` :

```
[client] 
# password       = your_password 
port            = 3307
socket          = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"

[mysqld]
port= 3307
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue,

1. Right click and open task manager
2. kill process "mysqld".
3. Open Xampp and start MySQL.

This really works!!

References:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcaqDv0f8K4

Answer (score 0):

Just open task manager and forcefully end the task named mysqld.exe. And then try once again.