# Unable connect to MySql in Xampp server

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

here I am trying to connect  mysql in xampp server but getting this message again and again.... I am able to connect apache.

```
Problem detected!
11:59:20 PM  [mysql]    Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL"!
11:59:20 PM  [mysql]    MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:59:20 PM  [mysql]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:59:20 PM  [mysql]    or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
11:59:20 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change your xampp  port number through `php.ini` file present in xampp/php folder. then restart your server and try to connect with that new port number.

Comment: is your xampp server , apache is running ?

Comment: I got this error once, the reason was I installed MySQL and then XAMPP which installed another instance of MySQL. Just change the port configuration as @anantkumarsingh said and you'll be ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xampp MySQL does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)