# typing Localhost wont take me to xampp webserver windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, xampp

I have installed the latest version of xampp 7.0.1 and after a bit of fiddling around had managed to get apache and MySQL connected.

Today neither Apache nor MYSQL connect.

Yesterday when Apache and MYSQL were connected I typed localhost/127.0.0.1 in to the browser to see if it takes me to the server page to ensure everything is installed correctly However, I kept on getting the http 404 error and no page would load regardless of which browser i tried. 
HTTP 404 error

This is what I get when I try to start Apache today:

```
Attempting to start Apache app...
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     Problem detected!
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports
free!
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the
blocking application
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen 
on a different port
```

And this is what I get when I try to start mysql:

```
Problem detected!
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     Port 3306 in use by "Unable to open process"!
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports 
free!
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the 
blocking application
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]     or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen
on a different port
```

That’s odd... Microsoft Edge can’t find this page

any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: does nobody know the answer to this query

Comment: It's not that people here haven't worked through these issues or don't care. It is rather that a video link may be required to examine the vast array of possible actions to take.

Comment: what would i need to record a video of to help get this sorted

Comment: short of letting someone in with Teamviewer or continuing to spend countless hours attempting things, it is too broad or unclear what the problem is. I would find someone local that has done it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the log you have mentioned,

```
4:27:44 PM  [mysql]  or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

It is asking you yo reconfigure MySQL on some different port as port 3306 is in use by some other process.

To solve it, follow [this link of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start) which has the solution for same problem you are having.