# MySql Error when I start mysql in xampp windows

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

When I start mysql in control panel I obtain this error:

```
Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
09:35:03  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
09:35:03  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
09:35:03  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
09:35:03  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
09:35:03  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
09:35:03  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xampp MySQL does not start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)

Comment: @Omore thank to your suggest but I have changed the file like in your link. But the error persists . Do you have some other suggests?

Comment: @Frante What are the logs saying? The error tells you to look in the logs. Could you place those here?