# Attempting to start MySQL app

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, wamp

When I install xampp server on window 7 after that I run a control panel of xampp.
then I start the apache service its done successfully but when I click to start the MySQL I view this type of error "Attempting to start MySQL app.." and myself didn't start what is the solution??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xampp MySQL does not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have anything else running on 3306? Skype has been known to run on 3306 which could be the issue. Try rebooting your machine and then launching xampp without launching anything else first.

If this doesn't work then please post error log

Answer (score 0):

Go to xampp/php/mysql/data 
Delete file name arial_log and then start mysql