# MySQL session won't start on XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

My MySQL won't start and it shows like this:

```
12:50:50  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
12:50:50  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
12:50:50  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
12:50:50  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:50:50  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:50:50  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
12:50:50  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

and then this is the error logs:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-03-05 12:50:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-05 12:50:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-05 12:50:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-05 12:50:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-05 12:50:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-05 12:50:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-05 12:50:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 300306; transaction id 171
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200305 12:50:48
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2020-03-05 12:50:48 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What is the cause of these errors and how can I rectify them?

Answer (score 7):

for this issue go to:

> c:\xampp\mysql\data\

and delete ALL FILES except DIRECTORIES.

just in case keep `my.ini`, if you got error again delete `my.ini` too.

Comment: try to change mysql port maybe another program is using the same port number

Comment: how is it? to change the mysql port?

Comment: here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177148/xampp-mysql-does-not-start/23864436#23864436

Comment: you saved the day. my backup software corrputed the mysql/data files especially the ibdata. i deleted it and re-run. it created new files and started the server

Answer (score 1):

**Very Very Easy**

Open xampp > mysql > backup copy everything from backup folder and paste everything in data folder copied from backup folder

Restart xampp and start all.Thanks.

Comment: It is the very easy way.

Comment: If it was very easy, the question was probably not here on stackoverflow. Stating something is easy is very subjective. A good explaination how it works, often works out best